# AndroidTV ImageView 4K resolution

Tags: android, android-tv

I am trying to get ImageViews to render 4K content, but it is only displaying it in 1080p.

If I provide the image in the correct size for 4K resolution, it just gets scaled down and displayed in 1080p anyway.

I am enabling the 4K display mode as follows, but it doesn't seem to affect ImageViews.

```
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.supportedModes.forEach {
        if (it.physicalHeight == 2160) {
            val params = window.attributes
            params.preferredDisplayModeId = it.modeId
            window.attributes = params
        }
```

Has anyone managed to render images in 4K correctly? Am I doing something wrong?
I couldn't find any recent guidelines on 4K support, but it seems strange that this is not supported now that 4K TVs are so common.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#4K-display

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, I've seen it, but that is back from 2015, when they launched 4K support only for video. I was hoping that there were improvements after so many years, but maybe not.

Comment: I would see if a 4K image on a SurfaceView is rendered in 4K. If that does/doesn't work please report back.